# JavaScript React component takes dictionary creates the aside bar with the li and link using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, iteration, jsx

I'm learning react and creating a blog along the way and on my articles I want to create a component that would take in a prop dictionary and the key would be the link the user can see and click on and the value would be the link for my routing. Thanks for any help.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


function AsideBar(props) {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Sidebar>
                <Nav>
                    {for (const property in props.link_short){
                        <Link='{props.link_short[property]}'><li>property</li></Link>
                    }}
                </Nav>
            </Sidebar>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default AsideBar
```

Comment: Are you sure the structure should be `<Link><li>..</li></Link>`? `<li>` should only be a direct child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: I didn't end up keeping it that way, but after so long of getting confused and frusterated I wasnt worried about the li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format for `Link` looks incorrect. It's missing `to` and single-quotes should not be used.

You also cannot use a `for` loop to output JSX since the result needs to be part of the return value. Instead, [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the [object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
{Object.entries(props.link_short).map(([ text, link ]) => (
  <li>
    <Link to={link}>{ text }</Link>
  </li>
))}
```